# Can I make a Nether clock (time) in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I want to make a pseudo-clock (time, not redstone) in the Nether. I was wondering if this had to be done using a command block with `/time query daytime` somehow. Is this possible in vanilla Minecraft?[image: Simple structure of what I'm trying to do, for reference]

Comment: Why is this tagged redstone if you don't want to use redstone?

Comment: @Penguin it's because I'm saying that I may have to use redstone, I don't know if I do. I've never tried to make a physical time clock in Minecraft before. Also, I want to see if I can use redstone lamps, which require redstone to be lit. (see my comment on the answer by aytimothy). What I meant by "not redstone" is that I don't want people accidentally thinking I'm trying to make a redstone _circuit_ clock.

Comment: How many clock hands do you want?  Also do you want in game time or IRL time?  Both are possible, but easier with a data pack.

Comment: @randomuser922 game time, and just 8 parts. the picture is basically how i want it to look, with one lamp being lit up for its 8th of the game's day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if you have a daylight detector on one side of a nether portal that shoots items through the portal and get detected on the other side. Then the detected signals would power certain parts of the clock.

Comment: Ok, this could work! All I need to do is make sure the nether portal doesn't merge with my current one, and everything should be good to go. Even if it doesn't work, I'll find some way to make a separate portal, so here's the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Try incrementing `time` (or any arbitrary scoreboard variable) by one every tick which can be achieved by using a repeat command block, preferably in spawn chunks.

Comment: but how would I correlate that to a physical "clock" ? What I'm trying to do is have redstone signals to redstone lamps for a larger-than-life clock so I can keep track of the time while in the Nether without `/time query daytime' every single time. Scoreboard does sound good, though.